# Pandas: Add columns by values of another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

This is quite a weird question, but I don't come along with it.

I do have two dataframes, named df1 and df2. There structure is:

```
df1:
Eval    Lang    Average     Model
df2:
Eval    Lang    Mean
```

The model column has exactly six different values available and there exists exactly one of these six for every possible combination (Eval, Lang). I want these six values to be six new columns in df2, all having the value of df1['Average'] in that position.

So the resulting structure then is:

```
Eval Lang Mean ModelAverage1 ModelAverage2 ModelAverage3 ModelAverage4 ModelAverage5 ModelAverage6
```

Is there an easy clever way to do this?
I am not sure anymore if what I am doing here is something which normal panda commands should support.

====
To visualise that, here is an example:
df1.csv:

```
Eval,Lang,Average,Model
F1,German,0.62,flairmulti
F1,German,0.7363,flairsingle
F1,German,0.72,bertmulti
F1,German,0.7527,bertsingle
F1,German,0.78,robertamulti
F1,German,0.7349,robertasingle
```

df2.csv

```
Eval,Lang,Mean
F1,German,0.54
Precision,German,0.54
Recall,German,0.53
```

The result would then be like:
total.csv

```
Eval,Lang,Mean,flairmulti,flairsingle,bertmulti,bertsingle,robertamulti,robertasingle
F1,German,0.54,0.62,0.7363,0.72,0.7527,0.78,0.7349
Precision,German,0.54,...
Recall,German,0.53,...
```

Of course there are also other values for Lang and Eval, but in fact, every pair of them has exactly these six named values of "Model" which I have above.

Comment: Will you please show a small sample of the two dataframes, and based on that, a small sample of your expected output? It would make it a lot easier to visualize your problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Give me five minutes :)

Comment: Done. I hope that helps. My problem is actually quite weird to describe. :) Happy for anybody who at least understands my desire

Comment: This is not a very strange request. I get it and will see what I can do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) `df2` to get the values from the `Model` column as the new columns and the values from the `Average` column as the new values:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1.pivot(index=['Eval', 'Lang'], columns='Model', values='Average').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
  Eval    Lang  Mean  bertmulti  bertsingle  flairmulti  flairsingle  robertamulti  robertasingle
0   F1  German  0.54       0.72      0.7527        0.62       0.7363          0.78         0.7349
```

Comment: You saved me once again, thank you very much! The pivot command is the final missing piece which I was searching for

Comment: Yep. It's really quite powerful, but it's tricky to learn how to use at times ;)